# Trocar ids por include no shortcode de galeria no Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, postgresql, shortcode

Estou usando o Postgre e ao criar galerias de imagens o shortcode é gerado automaticamente assim: `[gallery ids="1,2,3,4,5"]`. Mas esse Banco de dados não aceita 'ids', devo colocar o 'include', ficando assim: `[gallery include="1,2,3,4,5"]`.
Não sei onde faço essa alteração no código.

Wordpress Versão 3.9.1

Usando o plugin PG4WP para rodar o Postgre

Obs. Usando 'ids' retorna esse erro:

> WordPress database error: [ERROR: function field(bigint, integer,
>   integer, integer, integer) does not exist LINE 1: ...ND
>   ((wp_posts.post_status = 'inherit')) ORDER BY FIELD( wp_... ^ HINT: No
>   function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to
>   add explicit type casts.] SELECT wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts WHERE 1=1
>   AND wp_posts.ID IN (56,55,54,53) AND (wp_posts.post_mime_type LIKE
>   'image/%') AND wp_posts.post_type = 'attachment' AND
>   ((wp_posts.post_status = 'inherit')) ORDER BY FIELD( wp_posts.ID,
>   56,55,54,53 ) LIMIT 0, 4

Comment: Qual a versão do WP?

Comment: Wordpress Versão 3.9.1

Comment: Acho que o problema não é esse, pois no fim das contas `ids` é convertido em `include` no processamento do shortcode. Ou se você usa `[gallery include="1,2,3,4,5"]` funciona? Qual solução você está usando pra rodar o PosgreSQL? Já leu [isto](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Alternative_Databases)?

Comment: plugin PG4WP para rodar o Postgre

Comment: Tem umas dicas para consertar o plugin em [Not working with 3.9](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/not-working-with-39-44)... Fiz outras duas perguntas no meu comentário anterior...

Comment: Quando uso [gallery include="1,2,3,4,5"] funciona. Essa dica de consertar o plugin eu já tinha feito.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O seguinte plugin é uma gambiarra para trocar `ids="` por `include="` a cada vez que um post for salvo.

Tenha em conta o seguinte:

- Tem que habilitar a opção de buscar e trocar em todos os posts quando o plugin for ativado. Sugiro um backup do banco de dados se for usar esta opção.
- Tem que ajustar a função `get_cpt_sopt_27852()` se quiser adicionar outros tipos de post (páginas, posts personalizados, como galeria ou portfolio).
- O search/replace é muito básico. O ideal seria uma RegEx... O search inicial é por `[gallery`, caso afirmativo e se o post tiver `ids="`, isso será substituido por `include="`.

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: (SOPT) Ajustar Gallery shortcode para PostgreSQL 
 * Plugin URI:  http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/28228/201
 * Description: Gambiarra para evitar erro no plugin de PostgreSQL.
 * Author:      brasofilo
 * License:     GPLv3
 */

# HABILITAR O SEGUINTE PARA ATUALIZAR TODOS OS POSTS NA ATIVAÇÃO DO PLUGIN
// register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'ativar_sopt_27852' );

add_action( 'save_post', 'salvar_sopt_27852', 10, 2 );

/**
 * Função auxiliar para definir os Post Types do plugin
 *
 # AJUSTAR array conforme necessário
 */
function get_cpt_sopt_27852()
{
    return array( 'post', 'page', 'portfolio' );
}

/**
 * Disparada na ativação do plugin
 * 
 * Atualiza todos os posts/post-types já publicados
 */
function ativar_sopt_27852()
{   
    $args = array( 
        'post_type'   => get_cpt_sopt_27852(),
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'post_status' => 'published' 
    );
    $posts = get_posts( $args );
    foreach ( $posts as $post )
    {
        if( FALSE !== strpos( $post->post_content, '[gallery' ) )
        {
            if( FALSE !== strpos( $post->post_content, 'ids="' ) )
            {
                $post->post_content = str_replace( 'ids="', 'include="', $post->post_content );
                wp_update_post( $post );
            }
        }
    }   
}

/**
 * Disparada a cada "Guardar" ou "Atualizar"
 */
function salvar_sopt_27852( $post_id, $post ) 
{
    // Auto save?
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE )  
        return;

    // Correct post_type
    if ( !in_array( $post->post_type, get_cpt_sopt_27852() ) )
        return;

    if( FALSE !== strpos( $post->post_content, '[gallery' ) )
    {
        if( FALSE !== strpos( $post->post_content, 'ids="' ) )
        {
            $post->post_content = str_replace( 'ids="', 'include="', $post->post_content );
            # Evita loop do plugin
            remove_action( 'save_post', 'salvar_sopt_27852' );       
            wp_update_post( $post );
            add_action( 'save_post', 'salvar_sopt_27852', 10, 2 );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Isso mesmo! obrigada! Muito bom encontrar pessoas disponíveis a nos ajudar! Valeu.